# How to cast an enum that is a field inside a struct?

Tags: struct, enums, casting, rust

Why does casting move `self` out of borrowed content?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Foo {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
}

struct Bar {
    f: Foo,
}

impl Bar {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.f); // "Two"
        println!("{:?}", Foo::Two as u8); // "2"
        println!("{:?}", self.f as u8); // error
    }
}

fn main() {
    Bar{f: Foo::Two}.bar();
}
```

Throws this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:15:26
   |
15 |         println!("{:?}", self.f as u8); // error
   |                          ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any information about it in the official sources, but it appears that `as` casts have move semantics, i.e. they consume the cast object; consider this shortened case:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Foo {
    Foo1 = 1
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::Foo1;
    let bar = foo as u8; // the cast moves foo

    println!("{:?}", bar); // ok
    println!("{:?}", foo); // error[E0382]: use of moved value: `foo`
}
```

In your case you were mutably borrowing `self`, so it couldn't be consumed (i.e. moved); if you changed the signature to `bar(self)` or made `Foo` copyable by deriving `Clone` and `Copy`, it would work.

Comment: You should definitely `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` for `Foo`. Since it can only ever be a pure integer, there's no reason to not copy them.